# Why is my Async method call Exception not being caught

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I thought that if I wrap the EndInvoke call with a try catch if an error is thrown then my catch block would handle it? I must being doing something wrong??? Has to be user error, just not sure what?

**EDIT:**
I get the "Exception was unhandled by user code" being thrown when I run this which is stopping the application.  If I step through the code I see that and then it will go to the catch block.  But, I would expect the catch block to handle this and not see the unhandled exception that is stopping the application?

Any suggestions appreciated.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


       Action myMethod = new Action(Program.FooOneSecond);

        Go("Go Method");

        IAsyncResult tag =
            myMethod.BeginInvoke(null, "passing some state");

        try
        {
            myMethod.EndInvoke(tag);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        string strState = (string)tag.AsyncState;

        Console.WriteLine("State When Calling EndInvoke: "
            + tag.AsyncState.ToString());


        Console.Read();
    }

    static int Work(string s) { return s.Length; throw null; }

    static void Go(string s) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    static void FooOneSecond()
    {
        // sleep for one second!
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // throw an exception
        throw new Exception("Exception from FooOneSecond");
    } 
}
```

Comment: The code seems to be correct, and Tudor has tested it. You must have missed some details. What is the console output in your case? What does `Work` method do here? It is not called, but `throw null` makes me nervous. Have you removed some code?

Comment: Strange, but it doesn't work on my machine ... I've copied this code too, but commented `Thread.Sleep(1000)` line accidently, and everything was fine. But after commenting it exception is not being thrown/caught. scarpacci, maybe you did same thing with thread.sleep?

Comment: I am just trying to understand async calls and exceptions so this is just a demo of that. When my try gets called the Foo method bombs and is not caught.

Comment: Have you tried to run the built executable? Does it finish successfully? I suppose you have some specific VS settings that make it stop on exceptions. I've tried the code both with and without the `Sleep`, I've tried both Debug and Release build. Everything works perfect. If you're still sure you've got the issue, then it's probably the time to start analyzing the configuration: which version of compiler do you use, which build of .NET is installed on your machine, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code and the exception gets caught every time...

Comment: Error is not caught in mine....is thrown and is unhandled when method is called in try

Comment: I am an idiot...when I run without debug I can see it going to catch block....sorry everyone...newbie mistake